# How to get highlighted or colored verbose from .vimrc at start-up

Tags: vim

I am trying to display some different colours for different messages on start-up, out of my .vimrc file. However none of the commands "echohl" or "echoerr" seem to be doing anything.

I even have tried a function that I have found:

```
" Error message
function! EchoError(err)
    echohl ErrorMsg | echo a:err | echohl None
endfunction
```

But this seems to be doing nothing but just printing the message in plain text. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During sourcing of `~/.vimrc`, the entire output subsystem isn't fully initialized yet; it's too early. (You also cannot use stuff like `input()` there for that reason.) In GVIM, any output from there causes a pop-up, as the GUI isn't up yet.

The way to tackle any output (if you need this at all; it's mostly annyoing to the user who wants to get to the text) is to delay the output display. You can hook into the `VimEnter` event for that:

```
autocmd VimEnter * echohl ErrorMsg | echomsg "My error here" | echohl None
```

Comment: Hi Ingo, works great. Thanks. This is only for me in debug mode, want to have a solid way to see what went wrong while my plugin loads. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just an extra question, do I have the option of making non-error messages appear for example, in "blue". Thanks!

Comment: You have to use / define a _highlight group` (`:hi`), which you can then use before `:echo[msg]` via `:echohl`.